# Simple IIS 7 regex with optional 1, 2 or 3 values

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make a regex match the following URL:

www.mydomain.com/newyear/food/maincourse/

and have it rewrite to
default.aspx?occasion=(newyear)&type=(food)&category=(maincourse)

It works fine with:

```
([_0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$
```

but I would want it to work with just **www.mydomain.com/newyear/food/** as well, and just rewrite with **category** empty.
The only way I can do this now, is by n00bing, and creating 3 rewrite rules - one for each value.

I'm pretty sure there's a smarter way, and please let me know. :)

Comment: One question: why 3 rules? I've added an answer which makes `type` *and* `category` optional, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be very simple, make the slashes and the last two tokens optional:

```
([_0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)/?$
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted it to do! Oh my, the efficiency of a questionmark. Thanks Kobi! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for 'less than simple', you can do unicode checking since urls can now accept them (though you may not choose them for your own domain above).

```
([[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]])+/?([[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]])*/?([[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]])*
```

Comment: What does unicode checking mean and what does :alpha: and :punct: mean? /n00b

Comment: @KasperFP to put it very bluntly and not as accurate as some would like, unicode is the international alphabet. all those fancey German and Spanish letters don't show up as a-z but they are considered an a-z in unicode.  alpha designates characters punc designates punctuation .,-" etc. Unicode characters are now allowed in web addresses so we'll have to start checking for them...maybe not yours but you never know eh? 80)))

Comment: aaah I understand.. Like our danish æ, ø and å letters, which I (until now I see) had to put in after a-z in my regexes. Thanks again, Keng :)

Comment: @KasperFP no prob...take a look at this site for a good overview of all the international issues with formatting and such...note it is written in an American perspective so just reverse everything and it still should be useful ;0)  Most surprising is the statement that there are more than 10 numbers....80O  http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html