# iis seo friendly url - inbound rule - optional parameters?

Tags: iis, iis-6, web, seo

I've used the URL rewrite feature in IIS 6 to create a SEO friendly URL on my site. The problem is, I've written a single page to handle a whole host of sub pages. I need the URL to have optional parameters.

For example, mysite.com/offers/bikes/weekly/32/red

would translate to mysite.com/offers/bikes.aspx?period=weekly&weeknum=32&color=red.
I'd like some parameters to be optional. For example, I could put

mysite.com/offers/bikes/weekly
mysite.com/offers/bikes.aspx?period=weekly

I would have in my script that nothing but the weekly has been set, so just show ALL weeks.

This will allow me to set various offers by week number. I should point out that this is a complete fabrication. It's just an example to see if it's possible??

Hope this is possible as at the moment if I leave off any parameters, it says page cannot be found.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a case of adding question marks to identify a parameter as "optional".

For example, ([_0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)/?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]*)/?$
(last two elements are optional)

Answer found here: [Simple IIS 7 regex with optional 1, 2 or 3 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216645/simple-iis-7-regex-with-optional-1-2-or-3-values)